# Node.js - to read the contents of large file

Tags: node.js

```
const testFolder = './zip_file/sit1_Wave2_Settlement_afx_formula (1)/data_dictionary/CM.173/';

const fs = require('fs');

fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {

    files.forEach(file => {

        console.log(file);

        fs.readFile(testFolder + file, 'utf8', function (err, contents) {
            console.log(contents);
        });
    });
})
```

if I execute the above code it shows like

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at fs.readdir (/Users/jayagk/Desktop/project/sam.js:7:10)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
```

but the coding is correct only because I executed in my lap it runs correctly. I don't know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

your readdir method throws an error, you have to handle it in the callback like this:

```
if(err) handleErr();

console.log(file);
//.....
```

Comment: As a note: While you are right that the op has to check if `err` is the, the error **not** thrown, but passed first argument to the _error-first callback_, an error that is thrown has to be catch using a _try-catch_ block.

Answer (score 0):

Get your same result when I run your code in my lap,and change the testFolder = "./dummy" (this folder not exist ).so may be because you  testFolder  specifies path not exists......

Comment: I know you're excited, but please try to keep your language under control. Think of Stack Overflow as more like Wikipedia than like Reddit.